# Safari app extension: change FROM field in preferences pane

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

do you know where I can change this field in safari app extension project?

[image]

(I am not writing 1password extension, this is just an example image)

From my findings it looks like the name is `name of containing app`. But I'd like to change that. Is it possible? Is there any plist.info key that can be set? Or build settings/project settings?

Previously in gallery extensions there was a key named `DeveloperIdentifier`. But this doesn't work.

EDIT:

The reason I need this to happen is this:

- I want to have a process named one way (long text)
- So I renamed the project to conform it
- then I realized that extension takes the name out of containing app

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the same:

- I stick with having containing app project named as I wanted to be presented in extension (as seen in screenshot)
- I've found out, that bundle name can be changed what I was previously realizing by changing project name

So this is not exactly an answer to my question, but I was able to achieve what I needed

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you wanted and what you did. But, the name can be modified with 'bundle display name' (CFBundleDisplayName) in your extensions info.plist. The second grey text, is the developer/team. Which you choose in the target settings.